# why do I need super() in Android?

Tags: java, android

From a Activity I am passing data to:

```
public FoodAdapter(BaseActivity activity, int ResoruceId, ArrayList <food> cake) {


}
```

However this gives me a error. To fix this I need super() with activity, ResoruceId and cake inside of it. Why do I need to have this super() and what does it do??

Thanks

Comment: its not because of Android but Java try to learn more about classes and sub-classes.

Comment: Also check on conventions: variables small "resourceId" and classes / types capitalised: "Food"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It initializes the superclass you've extended. You need to do that, because the superclass *must* be initialized prior to any other code in your constructor running, because subclasses are allowed to access their superclass's state, and the superclass must have a chance to set up that state. And in general, just as your class has a chance to do initialization (in your constructor), the superclass needs a chance to do it as well.

If the superclass only defines constructors with arguments, you must call the superclass constructor explicitly (with `super`), passing in those arguments. So if it needs the activity and resource ID, then:

```
super(activity, ResoruceId); // I would change that second name!
```

If the superclass defines a constructor with *no* arguments, and you don't put a call to `super(...)` in your constructor, the Java compiler will insert one for you calling the no-args version (e.g., it inserts `super();` at the top of your constructor). But it can't do that if the superclass doesn't define a zero-args constructor.

I suggest reading up on the basics of inheritance in Java. Oracle has [an inheritance tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), including [this bit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) about using `super`.